# Foreach Loop Increment a total based on a higher number

Tags: php, arrays

I am calcuating scores and only want to collect the higher score. This is coming from a Laravel collection.

I current have 4 scores.

> 5,4,5,4

Two of those scores are from the same video_id. So I would like to only increment my total, If the next score in the iteration is higher than the previous number.

My array looks as follows :

```
array:4 [
  0 => array:9 [
    "hazard_score_id" => 2
    "user_id" => 17019
    "hazard_score" => 5
    "hazard_video_name" => "Clip 1"
    "hazard_video_id" => 111860212
    "hazard_video_section" => "theory"
    "created_at" => "2017-09-05 08:36:45"
    "updated_at" => "2017-09-05 08:36:45"
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
  1 => array:9 [
    "hazard_score_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 17019
    "hazard_score" => 4
    "hazard_video_name" => "Clip 2"
    "hazard_video_id" => 111860215
    "hazard_video_section" => "theory"
    "created_at" => "2017-09-05 08:39:26"
    "updated_at" => "2017-09-05 08:39:26"
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
  2 => array:9 [
    "hazard_score_id" => 4
    "user_id" => 17019
    "hazard_score" => 5
    "hazard_video_name" => "Clip 3"
    "hazard_video_id" => 111869861
    "hazard_video_section" => "theory"
    "created_at" => "2017-09-05 08:40:40"
    "updated_at" => "2017-09-05 08:40:40"
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
  3 => array:9 [
    "hazard_score_id" => 5
    "user_id" => 17019
    "hazard_score" => 4
    "hazard_video_name" => "Clip 1"
    "hazard_video_id" => 111860212
    "hazard_video_section" => "theory"
    "created_at" => "2017-09-05 10:20:19"
    "updated_at" => "2017-09-05 10:20:21"
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
]
```

I've made an attempt to do this, But my number is just returning 0 each time.

```
// Get Total Score (Based on Best Scores)
$total = 0;
$best_score = 0;

foreach($scores as $score)
{
    $video_id = $score->hazard_video_id;
    $best_score = $score->hazard_score;

    if($best_score > $score->hazard_score)
    {
        $total += $best_score;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: maybe I'm wrong but... Isn't the problem that `if($best_score >= $score->hazard_score)` is never going to return `True`?

Comment: is it supposed to collect separate best scores per video ID?

Comment: Hi @ADyson yes, It is

Comment: I only ask because the snippet doesn't seem to create a separate score variable for each video.

Comment: Remember to always grap paper and a pencil, and manually execute your code, especially if it's this short. This way you'll find mistakes like this one very easily c:

Comment: @ADyson I've modified my code. There is a video_id available as a var.

Comment: Nice suggestion @Shinratensei will use that in future

Comment: yes there is a video ID available, but you don't use it for anything. It has no effect on the score variable, which is potentially incremented regardless of the video ID. if you want separate scores per video ID you'll need an array of scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding-up `$total` within `foreach` loop you cannot "lookahead" to make a decision if there are any "next score" for the video, nor analyse if the score is higher. Instead you need to go through the whole collection to find the highest scores per video and then total them:

```
$best = [];
foreach($scores as $score) {
    if (!isset($best[$score->hazard_video_id])) {
        $best[$score->hazard_video_id] = 0; //assuming 0 is less then the minimal possible score. 
    }
    if ($score->hazard_score > $best[$score->hazard_video_id]) {
        $best[$score->hazard_video_id] = $score->hazard_score;
    }
}
$total = array_sum($best);
```

Comment: Thank You! I was looking at Laravels' collection counters and the likes too, Works a treat

Answer (score 1):

```
if($best_score >= $score->hazard_score)
{
    $best_score = $score->hazard_score;
    $total += $best_score;
}
```

The `$best_score` is always zero you should change it; Also use only `<` comparison otherwise you will add 5 two times.

```
if($best_score < $score->hazard_score)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to invert your condition, this way :

```
if( $score->hazard_score >= $best_score)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add following line

```
if ($best_score === 0)
{
    $best_score = $score->hazard_score;
}
```

to your loop. And this should be

```
if($best_score >= $score->hazard_score)
```

inverted.